# Weight vector dependence

Tags: forces, newtonian-gravity, weight

Does the weight of a person depend on the number of people or other bodies in say a room?

If so,why?

Was thinking about it earlier and want to find out from others.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking if people in a room change your weight?

Comment: Since you have weight with respect to earth and the people in the room, will that have a net weight on you. You must understand vector additions to get the question.

Comment: Sure, but this question is rather general. But no problem, you just get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the weight you'd measure if you stood on a scale, to a very small extent, yes. If there are other objects nearby me, chances are some will have some extra pull upwards, and some extra pull downwards. The direction and magnitude however will be small, if you're talking about everyday objects/people in a room.

Say one person, 60kg is standing about 1m away from me. This has a gravitational attraction that is $\sim10^{-9}$ the gravitational attraction from the earth. This is likely immeasurable. On top of that, it depends where their centre of mass is relative to me. For example, if they're taller than I am such that their centre of mass is above mine, then the net attraction will tend to decrease my apparent weight on my scale, if you could perceive it.